# ImapLibrary- Robot Framework: How to check total of mail inbox or check when no email in mailbox

Tags: robotframework, imaplib

Currently, I use a robot framework-ImapLibrary for open mail to check context mail, then I have a function to click "Don't Send email", So How to check mail in the mailbox that actually I don't recieve an email.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: How would you check it manually? Stare for some time at the mailbox, and declare "yep, no mail.", eventually; maybe come back tomorrow and see it's still empty. Or, observe the SUT's logs, if you don't want to stare at an empty mailbox ;) offtopic, though. Do the first in your case - loop for some time checking the mailbox for total/new mails, asserting none were received after you took the "Don't Send email" action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these keywords to check if email is not sent after executing "Don't send email" function.

```
Run Keyword And Expect Error    Some Error    Wait For Email    sender=noreply@domain.com  folder=INBOX  subject=Some Subject
```

P.S. Replace "Some Error" with error what is returned from `Wait For Email` keyword. Make sure you have `Open Mailbox` before using above keyword.